# Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'update' method on a 'Collection' object it is failing because no such method exists

Tags: pymongo

I am trying to save a record into mongo db using pymongo. I have the script to update the collection if it exists or insert one record. This snippet works when run interactively, but when I try to do the same from docker, the script fails with the error - Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'update' method on a 'Collection' object it is failing because no such method exists.

```
    def store_failed_cbsd(id,data,collection_name,mongo_client):      
      output_content = {'_id' : id,'data' : [data]}   
      key = {'_id': id}    
      mongo_client.get_database()[collection_name].update(key,    
      output_content, upsert=True)
```

PyMongo Version - 4.1.1
What am I missing?

Answer (score 9):

`update()` was deprecated for pymongo 4. Use `update_many()` or `update_one()` instead.

https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrate-to-pymongo4.html#collection-update-is-removed